# How to Set Limit for options.FindOne() in go mongo-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, driver, mongo-go

I see there is a way to `SetLimit()` for `Find()` func,  But I don't see any options to set limit for `FindOne()` , Since we are searching single result out of `FindOne()` we don't even have to limit it ? Automatically it handles limit ?

Tried setting limit using 1options.FindOne()` , But I do not see a way to do that .

Comment: `findOne` by definition returns only a single document. so it's basically default value limit(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not documented, but it's common sense that [`Collection.FindOne()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.FindOne) implies a behavior of that of `Limit=1`. The return value of `Collection.FindOne()` doesn't give access to multiple result documents, that's why [`options.FindOne`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#FindOneOptions) doesn't even have a `SetLimit()` method.

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/v1.10.3/mongo/collection.go#L1371), it's in there:

```
// Unconditionally send a limit to make sure only one document is returned and the cursor is not kept open
// by the server.
findOpts = append(findOpts, options.Find().SetLimit(-1))
```

Note that [`FindOptions.Limit`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#FindOptions.Limit) documents that:

```
// Limit is the maximum number of documents to return. The default value is 0, which means that all documents matching the
// filter will be returned. A negative limit specifies that the resulting documents should be returned in a single
// batch. The default value is 0.
Limit *int64
```

Comment: thanks for the response , this is useful .